# Minecraft Plugin: Get Block Type at specific coordinates

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am just learning how to create inventory GUIs in Minecraft. I am adding one to my call of duty zombies game that I have already built just to make it a little bit better. My problem is that when people buy team upgrades I need the inventory options to change to reflect what they have bought and what they have not bought.

The way I was planning to do this was to simply check for scoreboard tags that are assigned to them when they purchase an item. However, I couldn't find a way to do this.

My next thought was to have it so that when they buy each upgrade it sets a block at specific coordinates to a certain material. for this example lets just say cords (100, 50, 200) and type Sandstone. If the block was sandstone then it will open up a whole separate UI that i would make allowing them to buy upgrade two. This process would repeat until all upgrades were bought with the block at cords 100, 50, 200 changing as upgrades were bought.

I have really a few questions.

1. Is there a better way to do this and if so please explain.
2. Even if there isn't a good way I would still like to know how in a plugin to set a block at specific coordinates not relative to the player to a certain block type.
3. Even if there isn't a good way I would also still like to know how to check what type of block is at a specific set of coordinates not relative to the player.

I didn't think code examples were necessary here but if you need any please let me know and I can edit them in.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide,
~Stone

Comment: Ty! I managed to get it to work. Took a few hours but I finally found another post on how to target players using scoreboard so all of the calculations and info gathering I need to do are done server-side now.

Comment: Are you using Bukkit? We have a [[tag:bukkit]] tag, which would be more appropriate on your question than [plugins].

Comment: Yes. I will use that next time, didn't know there was a Bukkit tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no good way to do this, but i can anser your questions,
2. In the World there is a method called getBlock(x,y,z) you can then call the setType method on that block, example:

   `p.getLocation().getWorld().getBlock(0,0,0).setType(Material.AIR);`
3. As in the second anser you can also get the type, Example:

   `if(p.getLocation().getWorld().getBlock(0,0,0).getTyp() == Material.AIR){
   //Check for air in the players world at 0,0,0
   }`